# C: incomplete file transfer through TCP server and client sockets

Tags: c, file, sockets, tcp

I am having trouble transferring files through TCP sockets in C. I send the files in little chunks of 8192 bytes from a server to a client. The issue is that the client receives the one before last incompletely and does not receive the last one at all.

Here are both relevant parts of the code.
server:

```
fd = open(filename,O_RDONLY);
    if (fd == -1)
    {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file --> %s", strerror(errno));

            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Get file stats */
    if (fstat(fd, &file_stat) < 0)
    {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error fstat --> %s", strerror(errno));

            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fprintf(stdout, "File Size: \n%d bytes\n", file_stat.st_size);
    sprintf(file_size, "%d", file_stat.st_size);

    /* Sending file size */
    len = send(peer_socket, file_size, sizeof(file_size), 0);
    if (len < 0)
    {
          fprintf(stderr, "Error on sending greetings --> %s", strerror(errno));

          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    fprintf(stdout, "Server sent %d bytes for the size\n", len);

    offset = 0;
    remain_data = file_stat.st_size;
    /* Sending file data */

        while(((sent_bytes = sendfile(peer_socket, fd,&offset, BUFSIZ))>0)&&(remain_data > 0))
        {
          remain_data -= sent_bytes;
          fprintf(stdout, "2. Server sent %d bytes from file's data, offset is now : %d and remaining data = %d\n", sent_bytes, offset, remain_data);
    }
```

and client side:

```
ecv(client_socket, buffer, BUFSIZ, 0);
    file_size = atoi(buffer);
    fprintf(stdout, "\nFile size : %d\n", file_size);

    //received_file = fclose(fopen(FILENAME, "w"));
    received_file = fopen(FILENAME, "w");
    if (received_file == NULL)
    {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open file --> %s\n", strerror(errno));

            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    remain_data = file_size;

    while ((remain_data > 0)&&((len = recv(client_socket, buffer, BUFSIZ, 0)) > 0))
    {
            fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), len, received_file);
            remain_data -= len;
            //if (remain_data < BUFSIZ)
            //  buffsize = remain_data;
            //bzero(buffer,BUFSIZ);
            //if (len == 0 || len != BUFSIZ)
            //  break;
            fprintf(stdout, "Received %d bytes , %d bytes remaining\n", len, remain_data);
    }
    //code for accelerator here

    fclose(received_file);
```

The output on server side looks like this (which seems to be correct):
[image]

But on the client side this is what I get:
[image]

From there the applications on both sides are stuck forever. Any idea what might cause the trouble?
Thanks for your answers

Comment: What's the size of the buffer that you have specified ? BUFSIZ ?? Is it the multiple of 8192 as you are expecting ? The 7932 bytes remaining in the end -> itself means that you are now having lesser number of bytes than what you are actually requesting i.e., 8192. Hence you are blocked, since recv is a blocking call. You can look at O_NONBLOCK flag but you will have to handle the error conditions.

Comment: http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/html/single/bgnet.html#sendtorecv - This is an invaluable link that solves lots of initial beginner queries. It did help me for sure.

Comment: hello thanks for your comments, BUFSIZ =8192. The 7932 remaining bytes dont match the 8192 bytes sent by the server (it is not the last chunk being sent so it should be full

Comment: What is sendfile()?

Comment: sendfile() is a function allowing to send a file to a socket directly from the file itself (without an extra buffer)

Comment: When your client read the fileSize at the start of the sent data, it accidentally read 8192 bytes instead of just the 256 bytes that the server sent for the fileSize.  (256 bytes seems excessive but it won't break anything.  However, it is absolutely essential that both sides agree on the size of that chunk.)

Comment: OK thanks for your observation. I am not sure wether the filesize matches on both sides I will check this out

Comment: @ottomeister, it turns out there was indeed a mismatch on the size of the buffer for the file size, and as well for the acknowledge message sent in the other direction, which were both causing troubles. No more issue after fixing that. If you want to copy your comment as an answer I'd be happy to validate it and close the issue. Thanks alot!

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but my comment was more of a nudge in the right direction than an actual answer so I'll just leave it as-is.  I'm glad you were able to fix the program.